# View progress on WCF streaming service side

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a streaming WCF service which allows clients to download files from the service. I have no problem displaying progress on the client side as that is the side reading the stream. However, I have been unable to think of a way (using streams) of showing progress on the service side. The only option I can think of is to ditch streaming mode and separate the file into chunks.

Is there any way around this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding, on the function you are calling on the service, an event handler that will report the progress as it happens on the service and log that somewhere when its function is invoked to do something from a client.

Although this example is implemented for the client I think something like the below would work for you:

[Upload progress in WCF](http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/upload-progress-in-wcf/)